# Laravel 4 JSON Response with Cookie

Tags: json

How can I set a cookie with a json response?

I noticed, for me at least, the following command is the only thing working that sets a cookie:

```
            return Redirect::to('/')
                ->withCookie(Cookie::make('blog', $cookie_values, 1000));
```

Of course if it was an ajax request it would return the target of the redirect.

How could I translate this to an ajax request and return a json response with the cookie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to set a cookie with a json response with the following code:

```
            $cookie_values = array(
                'name' => Input::get('name'),
                'id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'login_success' => 1);

            if(Request::ajax())
            {                    
                $cookie = Cookie::make('blog', $cookie_values, 1000);
                $response = Response::json($cookie_values);
                $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);

                return $response;
            }
```

Comment: with L8, I'm using `response()->json()->cookie($cookie)` should work with previous version also I guess!

Answer (score 1):

Great hint!

Having a look at Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag also revealed how to set headers for a json response when having problems with HTTP access control:

```
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '/* your subdomain */');
```