# How to send cookie from backend (laravel) to frontend?

Tags: laravel, rest, cookies, vue.js

I would like to send the Bearer token and save it as cookie in frontend.

I pass cookie like this:

```
return response()->json([
    'remember_token' => $user->remember_token,
], 200)->withCookie(cookie('auth_token', 'random_token', 3600));
```

But it is not setting the cookie at all! Please help!

Comment: You may try this: `Cookie::queue($name, $value, 3600);` OR `$response = Response::make('Hello World'); $response->withCookie(Cookie::make('name', 'value', $minutes));`

Comment: I tried with `withCookie(Cookie::queue($name, $value, 3600))`! But this didn't work

Comment: Your edited answer also didn't work at all! By the way, frontend and backend are on different domains

Comment: Can you please try this one: `return response('Hello World')->cookie(
    'name', 'value', $minutes
);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$cookie = Cookie::make('auth_token', $user->remember_token, 3600);
$response = Response::json('remember_token' => $user->remember_token, 200);
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
return $response;
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15017977/10625611).